# Tomcat 8.5 gzip compression does not work

Tags: java, tomcat, gzip

I want to apply compression to my responses at tomcat level however it does not work. It seems like an esay protocol, however somehow I am unable to apply it. Here is my connector conf in server.xml

```
<Connector port="80" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Nio2Protocol"
           maxThreads="500"
           processorCache="500"
           maxConnections="10000"
           acceptCount="5000"
           URIEncoding="UTF-8"
           useSendfile="false"
           compression="force"
           compressionMinSize="4"
           noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata"
           compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,text/javascript"/>
```

I disabled antivirus on my local macihne(Client-side) and the requests have Accept-Encoding:gzip header. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please go through the post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16690321/need-step-by-step-overview-for-compression-on-tomcat

Comment: I have already gone through that post and applied the suggesstions, but they did not work for me.

Comment: Did you try setting `compression="on"` ? Also have a look at this too - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30608952/tomcat8-gzip-compression-for-css-js

Comment: Yes, i did. It was set to on, and in another post someone has suggested to change it into force. So I tried force too but neither on nor force worked.

Comment: Moreover I am trying to access the tomcat inside the server gzip compression seems ok, but from browsers the problem still occurs 
    curl -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch" -I  http://localhost
    HTTP/1.1 405
    Allow: GET, POST
    Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
    Content-Language: en
    Transfer-Encoding: chunked
    Content-Encoding: gzip
    Vary: Accept-Encoding
    Date: Mon, 07 Nov 2016 12:38:30 GMT

Answer (score 1):

Too late but:

Note: There is a tradeoff between using compression (saving your bandwidth) and using the sendfile feature (saving your CPU cycles). If the connector supports the sendfile feature, e.g. the NIO2 connector, using sendfile will take precedence over compression. The symptoms will be that static files greater that 48 Kb will be sent uncompressed. You can turn off sendfile by setting useSendfile attribute of the protocol, as documented below, or change the sendfile usage threshold in the configuration of the DefaultServlet in the default conf/web.xml or in the web.xml of your web application.